# Smaller vs. less vs. lesser

Tags: adjectives, word-usage, vocabulary, numbers, comparatives

I am confused as to some of the vocabulary that can be used to compare numbers and quantities, and would very much appreciate some clarification.

- I suppose it is safe to say that 1 is smaller than 2.
- Can I also say that 1 is less than 2, and if so, which form is preferable?
- It seems that saying that 1 is lesser than 2 is uncommon - but is it incorrect?
- Finally, -2 is clearly less than -1, but is it true that -2 is smaller than -1?
  (If I have 2$ of debt, then I would say that I have less money than if I had 1$ of debt, but I would also say that my debt was *larger*, not smaller).

Comment: As a general rule, "smaller" is used for size, whereas "lesser" is used for quantity.

Comment: Related (but probably not a dup) [“Lower number” vs. “smaller number”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26471/l)

Comment: @FumbleFingers What? How does "5 is smaller than 3" work, please?

Comment: @Wonder Don't you think in that context "smaller" is used for size; a measure of quantity, while "lesser" is used for quality?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: I posted that link over 8 years ago, to a question + discussion from over **10** years ago, so I don;t really remember all the details. But as to that specific "visual pun" used by some teacher *decades* ago to justify saying that the digit "5" in a small font is "smaller" than "3" in a *large* font - I didn't think much of it, and I apparently *downvoted* that answer. Note that my own answer there includes the line *I have no opinion on whether either of OP's examples is more 'correct' than the other.* (I'm not generally a "prescriptivist" today, and obviously never was! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm glad you took the trouble to explain that. It hurts to confess this, and I'd got so tied up on the arithmetic route I didn't at all see "5 is smaller than 3" Duh!

Answer (score 11):

The *<* symbol is known as *less than* so *less than* will probably be better in mathematical contexts. In other contexts *smaller than* may also be acceptable: *My salary is smaller than my wife's*.

*Lesser* can only be used attributively. So you can say: *I earn a lesser salary than my wife*, but not: *My salary is lesser than my wife's*.

Answer (score 9):

**Small**

*Small* is an adjective (and sometimes an adverb or noun) [meaning](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/small_1)

> not big; less in size or amount than is average
>
> *a small business*
>
> *small lunches*
>
> *He’s small for his age*
>
> *Those jackets come in small, medium, and large sizes*

It does not require an explicit comparison to any other item for its meaning, although such comparison may be understood or implied.

> I ordered a small cup of coffee. (I did not order a large cup.)

**Smaller**

*Smaller* is the relative adjective (or sometimes adverb or noun) of *small*, indicating that referenced term it has more of the characteristic of *smallness*

> I ordered the *smaller* of the two cup sizes offered.

When using small, no other size needs to be explicitly considered.  When using smaller, there must be a point of comparison, and generally only two choices.  If there were more than two, referring to the item having the least of the characteristic, you would use *smallest*.

**Less**

*Less* is a determiner or pronoun that [means](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/less?q=less)

> a smaller amount of; not as much:
>
> [as determiner]:
>   *the less time spent there, the better*
>
> [as pronoun]:
>   *storage is less of a problem than it used to be*
>
> *they returned in less than an hour*

*Less* requires an explicit comparison.  Even When you say *I want less*, you are asking for an amount that is not as large as the specific one being offered.

Note that *less* is generally used only with uncountable things. *I want less sugar in my coffee*.  When referring to countable things (things with discrete indivisible units), *fewer* is used. *I want fewer people at my dinner party.*

**Lesser**

*Lesser* [means](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/lesser)

> Smaller in amount, value, or importance, especially in a comparison between two things: *chose the lesser evil.*
>
> Of a smaller size than other, similar forms: *the lesser anteater.*

*Lesser* refers to something discrete and is a specific comparison between two things. *Less* is also comparative, but does not refer to an explicit amount.

> *I want less sugar.* [How much? Not clear.]
>
> *I want the soda with the lesser amount of sugar.* [How much? The exact amount in the diet drink.]

**The Questions**

1 is *smaller* than 2

1 is *less* than 2

1 is the *lesser* number when compared to 2

Which you use depends totally on the context. Whether a higher integer means *more* depends on what you mean when you say *more* - as you suggest more debt means less cash.

This is even more complex when considering negative numbers.  Which is *greater,* -1 or -2. If you are discussing temperature -2 is colder (more cold) that -1.

Answer (score 1):

I'll chime in as a scientist to give a different perspective.

**Everyone would agree that "less" and "smaller" are synonyms for positive numbers.** In other words, we would agree that "5 is less than 10" and "5 is smaller than 10" are both true.

**The difference between "less than" and "smaller than" is more subtle when negative numbers are included.** In terms of pure math alone, many find it acceptable to say both that "-6 is less than -4" and "-6 is smaller than -4". (This is sometimes taught in primary school classrooms in the USA.) This makes some kind of sense: if you're comparing a person with a debt of $4 to a person with a debt of $6, the person with the debt of $4 has *less* money and therefore a *smaller* net worth. But as @bib suggested in their answer above, a debt of $4 is *smaller* than a debt of $6.

However, as many have pointed out, "smaller than / larger than" compares *size*. The "size" of (-4) is smaller than the "size" of (-6). For this reason, many mathematicians, engineers and scientists prefer to use "smaller than/larger than" for comparing absolute values -- but this is not universal.

So, in mathematical language, there are sometimes ambiguities in what somebody says. What word to use depends on the kind of comparison you're making. If you aren't sure what to say, perhaps you could be more precise (e.g. give values) or say it a different way (to avoid confusion). If you aren't sure what somebody else means by it, you can always ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

To me it's clear this belongs not in English Language Usage, but rather English Language Learners or, rather, some arithmetic or maths forum. Who doubts that?

That aside, you can say that 1 is less than 2. Can you give some examples why you might doubt that?

Comparing 1 and 2 in arithmetic, both *less* and *smaller* are correct. Neither is preferable.

Saying 1 is *lesser* than 2 is uncommon because *less* and *lesser* are very different; they do not compare or contrast the same things.

*Less* is a straight comparison of quantity. *Lesser* is normally used to compare quality.

*Less* might compare the simple weight or cost of oak or pine to be used by a carpenter. *Lesser* would compare which wood was more aesthetically desirable.

The whole idea is complicated by the fact that *lesser* can also be a plural form of *less*… In dice games, five and (any) *lesser* numbers will be beaten by six…

It is true that -2 is smaller than -1. How could it not be?

Quite separately, whether you have $2 of debt or merely $1 makes no difference to how much money you have. It will make a difference to have much money you have left after you've settled your debts, and that's different.

That aside yes, a $2 debt is larger than one of $1.

Answer (score -1):

Small/large refer to size. One number is not smaller than another unless you are talking about font size.

2 is less than 1.

You would use "lesser" in cases where "greater" would be appropriate in the reverse. 5 is greater than 4, so 4 is lesser than 5. But it would also be appropriate to say 4 is less than 5.

Regarding debt, a debt of $2 is greater than a debt of $1. The value is a number, so use greater/less.

Comment: I like the thrust of this answer, though I might quibble with its premise (language is not so precise as you paint it). Nevertheless, we encourage answerers here to support their arguments with references to external authorities (dictionary, usage guides, the opinions of experts, what-have-you).